# Problems with rounding giving too many digits

Tags: formatting, rounding

My current code is:

```
round = .1;
f[x_] := x + 4 - Sqrt[3 x^2 - 5]
xx = Solve[f[x] == 0, Reals];
StringForm["x=`1`", 
If[Length[xx] >= 1, Round[Max[xx[[All, 1, 2]]], round], 
"none"]]
```

> x=5.800000000000001`

which i want to give me an output of "x = 5.8" instead.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: `StringForm["x=`1`", 
 If[Length[xx] >= 1, 
  Round[Max[xx[[All, 1, 2]]], round // Rationalize] // N, "none"]]`

Comment: Could round exactly and then use `N`: `N[Round[Max[xx[[All, 1, 2]]], 1/10]]`

Answer (score 5):

You could add a [`StandardForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StandardForm) wrapper:

```
StringForm["x=`1`",StandardForm @ If[Length[xx]>=1,Round[Max[xx[[All,1,2]]],round],"none"]]
```

> x=5.8

Comment: Thank you! that worked and i have no idea why, i'll read the documentation for standardForm

Answer (score 4):

```
StringForm["x=`1`", If[Length[xx] >= 1, 
  DecimalForm[Round[Max[xx[[All, 1, 2]]], round], DefaultPrintPrecision -> 2], 
  "none"]]
```

> x = 5.8

Same result with `NumberForm` in place of `DecimalForm`.

Comment: Thank you, this worked great

Answer (score 2):

```
StringJoin["x=",If[Length[xx] >= 1, ToString[Round[Max[xx[[All, 1, 2]]]*10]/10.]]]
```

> x = 5.8

`Round[q*10]` rounds `10q` to the nearest integeger.

`Round[q*10]/10` rounds `q` to the nearest tenth.

`ToString` turns an expression into a string and `StringJoin` joins strings, both aptly named ...

Comment: Just fixed a typo (was missing a right bracket (`]`)).